# Java interface Start/Stop already exist?

Tags: java, interface

Does an interface with this contract

```
start();
stop();
```

Already exist?

I have the impression to recode something classic here...

Comment: An interface is normally very light. There's no real problem in having your own, and it means you'll be able to change it easily.

Comment: What do you want to use it for?

Comment: Depending on your requirement, you might want to call the methods `open` and `close` and implement `Autocloseable` to allow using try-with-resources (obviously not necessarily applicable to your use case).

Comment: @assylias It's worth noting that `AutoClosable`, as well as `try-with-resources` are only available from Java 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`org.springframework.context.Lifecycle`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html)

Comment: I'm not sure importing a org.springramework interface in a totally unrelated application would be a good idea.

Comment: @dystroy If an app uses the springframework, then it is the most appropriate interface to use. If it doesn't use yet, then it should ;).

Comment: I already have this package, so it is perfect for me now. Perhaps later I will create my interface if it differ from LifeCycle, but now it is just perfect.

Comment: If your use case is not bean context lifecycle, then you are just making a mess of your code. You are also tying your code to Spring in a completely new way.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, but I'd say even if it does, it'd be much handier to write your own just in case in the future you need to amend it and add a `pause();` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not without including additional packages, but it's quite easy to create one:

```
public interface StartAndStoppable { //I am *terrible* at coming up with names :P
    public void start();
    public void stop();
}
```

This is good because you can also add new methods if needed later.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard about such interface among standard Java classes.

But something distantly remining what you are looking for could be class `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask` with methods `run()` and `cancel(boolean)`.

Answer (score 0):

If clean naming is not so critical as requirement to use standard Java, then:

> - java.lang.Runnable.run() as start()
> - java.io.Closeable.close() as stop()

"io" package might be confusing, but sounded OK for starting/stopping embedded web server. 
The reason of not inventing your own interface might be complete modules decoupling without introducing third module (containing just newly invented interface).

Comment: Yes, but if `run` and `close` are coming from different interfaces, you can't pass them as a single type containing both the methods, except by passing the reference to the implementation class itself, which then misses the entire point.

Comment: Right. Sorry, did not thought that would be a problem (since I required only one method at once). Nevertheless you can accept both interfaces as one argument:

`public <T extends Runnable & Closeable> void manage(T component) throws IOException {
 component.run();
 component.close();
}`

Comment: That's actually a nice idea to make an interface that extends both. As a slight tweak to that idea (if you're using JDK 7 or higher), you could extend [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) instead of [Closeable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) to get rid of the confusion around the "io" package and exceptions.